# How to make an Windows 10 app?

Tags: javascript, c#

I like to start developing for Windows 10, I can program JavaScript and a little bit of C#, where do I start to make a Windows 10 app?

Comment: A quick search on the internet would have helped. But here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173060(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start programming for Windows 10 you need the free [Visual Studio 2015 Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions).

You can write Windows 10 app's in JavaScript , C# or C++.

The best place how to start programming for Windows 10 is on https://developer.microsoft.com/getstarted

If you need more training to build app's for Windows 10, we have a lot of free training here: [MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windowsapp/1171/build-windows-10-universal-app-first-look

I found this on internet..This one would help you..